# How to get the fingers count in the InkCanvas?

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I am trying to zoom the InkCanvas when the finger counts greater than 1, but I can't get the finger count in the InkCanvas.Anyone Please help me how to get the finger count in InkCanvas.

Comment: I've asked the Microsoft Ink team for this exact feature. Still not available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have touch screen to test but maybe this will work:

```
    int count;

    private void InkCanvas_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
    }

    private void InkCanvas_PointerExited(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count--;
    }
```

If it doesn't help. Try to use `PinterPressed` and `PointerReleased`. You may grab point **Id** from event **args** and handle them.

Comment: This doesn't work with zooming. `DirectManipulation` kicks in and absorbs the pointer events.

Comment: Yes.. it not worked.  I tried this  InkPath.InkPresenter.ActivateCustomDrying();
            InkPath.InkPresenter.SetPredefinedConfiguration(InkPresenterPredefinedConfiguration.SimpleMultiplePointer);                                                             Now i can get the finger count in StrokeStarted event, but i am getting the StrokeContainer value is null because of using the custom drying.

Comment: @Santhiya The document says: If custom dry mode is enabled (ActivateCustomDrying ), StrokeContainer is null. Do you solve you issue about get the fingers count in the `InkCanvas`?